# How to make vim and netrw re-read windows user accounts (or manage accented user names)

Tags: windows, vim, accounts, netrw

I changed an user account in Windows Vista, but when I reopen Vim and netrw (with `:e .`) I still 'see' the old user name. How can I somehow make vim re-read the windows users info?

On a side note: i changed the user because netrw fails to work properly with accented user names (like josé). It opens them, but then fails with subdirectories, wich shows preceded with `'<a9>'`

Any clue? ty.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem with accented characters in windows user accounts: check your encoding! You'll want to make sure that the encoding your shell is using is the same one you've got netrw/vim using.  I can see similar behavior when making a directory entry using latin1 but using utf-8 with vim+netrw (in that case, its showing a `<e9>`).